# Pasar variable desde php a ajax y redireccionar mediante location.href

Tags: ajax

tengo una funcion en ajax que recibe parametros de formulario y los procesa en un archivo php que busca el registro, si coincide lo redirecciona a otra pagina, caso contrario muestra mensaje de error. El problema es que no logro que pase el parametro $id para redireccionar, me recibe el valor 2 del echo. Adjunto codigo. Es un sistema para validar y activar usuarios. Agradeceria su colaboracion y gracias.

**Archivo Ajax:**

```
submitHandler: function(form){
                    var thisForm = $(form);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "sesuser.php",
                        data: thisForm.serialize(),
                        success: function(msg){
                            $("#alert").show();
                            $("#alert").html("<strong>Procesando...</strong>");
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert').fadeOut('slow');
                            }, 4000);

                            if(msg == "1"){
                                $("#alert").html("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos... Por favor intente nuevamente.</div>");
                            }else if(msg == "2"){
                           /// aqui esta mi problema ////
                                var objJson=JSON.parse(msg);
                                location.href ='activar?id=' + objJson;
                            }else if(msg == "3"){
                                window.location.href="index";
                            }

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert').fadeOut('slow');
                            }, 4000);
                            $("#iniciar")[0].reset();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

**Archivo PHP:**

```
if ((isset($_POST['correo'])) and (isset($_POST['passw1']))) {

    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM visitantes");
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    if ($fila){
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['correo']);
        $pass    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['passw1']);
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM visitantes WHERE correo = '" . $usuario. "' and clave = '" . md5($pass) . "'");

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $act = $row['activado'];
            if ($act == "0"){
                $id = $row['id_vis'];  // no logro pasar este parametro $id ////
                echo "2";
            }else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id_vis'];
                $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['usuario'];
                $_SESSION['usr_tipo'] = $row['id_tipo'];
                $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"]=date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
                echo "3";
            }
        } else {
            echo "1";
            //$errormsg = "Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos!!!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas devolver un array con tus dos valores y luego usarlos uno en la comparación y otro en la redireccios. Ahora mismo estas usando el mismo valor en ambas.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes retornar un JSON desde PHP con los dos valores que te interesan, por ejemplo:

```
...
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $act = $row['activado'];
            if ($act == "0"){
                $id = $row['id_vis'];  
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 2,'id' => $id)); //valor para el control y el id
            }else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id_vis'];
                $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['usuario'];
                $_SESSION['usr_tipo'] = $row['id_tipo'];
                $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"]=date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 3,'id' => ''));
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 1,'id' => ''));
            //$errormsg = "Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos!!!";
        }
...
```

de esta forma puedes acceder desde js a los valores y redireccionar según corresponda:

```
submitHandler: function(form){
                    var thisForm = $(form);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "sesuser.php",
                        data: thisForm.serialize(),
                        success: function(msg){
                            var objJson=JSON.parse(msg);
                            $("#alert").show();
                            $("#alert").html("<strong>Procesando...</strong>");
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert').fadeOut('slow');
                            }, 4000);

                            if(objJson.status == "1"){
                                $("#alert").html("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>Usuario o Contraseña incorrectos... Por favor intente nuevamente.</div>");
                            }else if(objJson.status == "2"){


                                location.href ='activar?id=' + objJson.id; //el otro valor en el json retornado
                            }else if(objJson.status == "3"){
                                window.location.href="index";
                            }

                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#alert').fadeOut('slow');
                            }, 4000);
                            $("#iniciar")[0].reset();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta muy util. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en que solo imprimes los status en numeros a la repuesta y eso es lo que ajax va mostrar si quieres pasar mas contenido a la repuesta se me ocurre lo siguiente

imprime en tu backend algo como la siguiente cadena:

```
echo "1|usuario";
```

en el resultado de ajax utiliza como delimitador el `|` para separar el resultado con `split`

```
var res = msg.split("|");
//res[0]; status
//res[1]; usuario
```

pero te recomiendo utilizar mejor json en el backend.

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'usuario' => $id));
```

antes debes agregar a tu ajax la opcion: `dataType: 'json'` para que este pueda entender que resultado va a retornar.

en tu repuesta ajax

```
msg.status //1
msg.usuario //id user
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboracion me fue util. Saludos